# Merging two dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframes

df1

| ind | stay | res |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB10 | yes | yes |
| AB11 | no | yes |

df2

| ind | date | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB10 | 22-01 | 1 |
| AB10 | 24-01 | 2 |
| AB11 | 20-01 | 1 |
| AB11 | 21-01 | 2 |
| AB11 | 22-01 | 3 |

I want following dataframe as a final one

| ind | date | c | stay | res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB10 |  |  | yes | yes |
| AB10 | 22-01 | 1 |  |  |
| AB10 | 24-01 | 2 |  |  |
| AB11 |  |  | no | yes |
| AB11 | 20-01 | 1 |  |  |
| AB11 | 21-01 | 2 |  |  |
| AB11 | 22-01 | 3 |  |  |

How to get this using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what your question asks:

```py
df1 = pd.concat([
    df1.reindex(columns=list(df2.columns) + list(df1.columns)[1:]),
    df2.reindex(columns=list(df2.columns) + list(df1.columns)[1:])]).sort_values('ind')
```

Output:

```
    ind   date    c stay  res
0  AB10    NaN  NaN  yes  yes
0  AB10  22-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  AB10  24-01  2.0  NaN  NaN
1  AB11    NaN  NaN   no  yes
2  AB11  20-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
3  AB11  21-01  2.0  NaN  NaN
4  AB11  22-01  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

If you want empty strings instead of `NaN` values, append `.fillna('')`:

```
    ind   date    c stay  res
0  AB10              yes  yes
0  AB10  22-01  1.0
1  AB10  24-01  2.0
1  AB11               no  yes
2  AB11  20-01  1.0
3  AB11  21-01  2.0
4  AB11  22-01  3.0
```

A slightly shorter alternative would be to use `concat()` first and then order the columns:

```py
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])[list(df2.columns) + list(df1.columns)[1:]].sort_values('ind').fillna('')
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is a `pd.concat()` for your dataframes

```
df_con = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_con.sort_values('ind').fillna('')
```